# Inject dependencies with Typhoon

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

I have a very basic question about dependency injection and Typhoon.

If I have the following code:

```
self.router = [[MyRouter alloc] initWithNavController:self.navigationController];
```

How can I define that `MyRouter` should be initialized with `self.navigationController`?

My assembly:

```
public dynamic func router() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MyRouter.self) { (definition: TyphoonDefinition!) in
            definition.useInitializer("initWithNavController:", parameters: { (method: TyphoonMethod!) -> Void in
                method.injectParameterWith(...)
            })
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to wire this dependency.

Thanks

Comment: Is your navigation controller known in advance? Then either create a definition or inject an object directly. Otherwise use a runtime arg. Let me know and we'll provide code sample.

Comment: @JasperBlues yes, it's known in advance. Could you provide a brief code sample?